# How to display sum value instead of count in line chart on Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, database, charts

I'm trying to display the sum of sales instead of the count by month and I tried using **dd();** and returns the sum but it doesn't display in my blade file and I can't seem to find other codes that I can use as a reference, I did find some but it doesn't work.

This is my controller

```
public function lineChart(){
       
        $saleData = sales::select(DB::raw("sum(reserved_qty) as reserved_qty"))
                    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw("Month(created_at)"))
                    ->pluck('reserved_qty');
    // This is the similar codes that I found as reference but still returns null in chart. I also tried using ->toArray(); after pluck
    // $saleDatas[] = $saleData;

        return view('lineChart', compact('saleData'));
    }
```

and in my blade

```
<body>
    <center><h1 style="color:red;">Sale Report</h1></center>
   
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var saleData = <?php echo json_encode($saleData)?>;
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Sales'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
                'October', 'November', 'December'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Sale Report'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Product Sold',
            data: saleData
        }],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snipped with the value `[6]` on `series.data` and this works well.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Sales'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
            'October', 'November', 'December'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Sale Report'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Product Sold',
        data: [6] // $saleData
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

On the blade view you must use the proper [tags](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#introduction) not php tags like you have done. With this you prevent displaying unescaped data:

`var saleData = {!! json_encode($saleData) !!};`

Other thing: On the `$saleData` you can do `->toJson()` so the [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-tojson) is right away JSON and clean on the view blade the `json_encode()` method.

Comment: The snippet works and I also did the`->toJson()` , `var saleData = {!! json_encode($saleData) !!};` it the chart display none but `dd();` shows that the data is being retrieved but unfortunately it is still not getting displayed in the chart

Comment: @NeedHalp can you change view() helper like this:  `view('lineChart', ['saleData' => $saleData]);`

Comment: unfortunately it's still not displaying anything

Comment: @NeedHalp manually put the value on the blade and check if it builds the chart.

Comment: I put the values manually and it does build the chart. My problem is probably with how I retrieve them into chart, I tried ```<?=$saleData?>``` and the data is displayed but not in the chart

Comment: @NeedHalp I was checking on [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-json) and seems it's fine to do `var saleData = <?php echo json_encode($saleData)?>;` on blades.. now why isn't passing the correct `var` value to the js that's strange.. do a `console.log('saleData')` and check if is array of int.

Comment: it is an array of string ```"["6","1","1"]"```

Comment: It works now I used ```$saleData = array_map('intval', json_decode($sale, true));``` to turn it into an array of ints.. tysm for your time of guiding me @francisco